# Conflict of the DELETE statement with the restriction REFERENCE

Tags: sql

When I try to excecute this code, I'm getting error:

*Conflict of the DELETE statement with the restriction REFERENCE "FK_Options_users". The conflict occurred in database "WINTOUR", table "PrintForm.Options", column 'user_code'*

Can't understand why and how to fix that.

```
declare

  @USER_CODE int;

select

  @USER_CODE = 24;

delete from Settings.Items where user_code =   @USER_CODE

delete from usnet where code =   @USER_CODE

delete from usgroups where usercode =   @USER_CODE

delete from users where code =   @USER_CODE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `Foreign Key constraint` exists between the `user_code` column in `PrintForm.Options` and the `code/user_code` column in given tables.

If you try to delete all the data in given tables an error will occur as the `user_code` column in  `PrintForm.Options` reference the data in the any one of the table from which yor are deleting the data.

To resolve the issue you should either drop and recreate the constraint `FK_Options_users` or delete the data from child table `PrintForm.Options` that the Foreign Key references ie where `user_code =  24`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are removing user 24, but the PrintForm.Options table has an entry that is still using it, and were it to be deleted, the foreign key would no longer be satisifed.

Have you perchance missed "Printform.Options" from the list of delete queries?

Answer (score 1):

You have a foreign key relation with one of the rows you are trying to delete. That means that the key is used in another table. You must delete in the correct order so that does not happen.

You are missing a delete for the elements in specified in the error. So in Database WINTOUR in the table PrintForm.Options the use_code is a foreign key to the usercode you are deleting.

so you need to add

```
 delete from PrintForm.Options where user_code = @USER_CODE
```

probably right before or after Settings.Items.